# how to use auth_setup_template in jBloomberg code

Tags: authorization, bloomberg, jbloomberg

I'm new to all around Bloomberg. Having trouble of figuring out how to use auth_setup_template from https://github.com/assylias/jBloomberg/tree/master/src/test/resources in jBloomberg code.

I have code that is using BLPAPI directly on which you can specify auth parameters. I'm interested how to use auth parameters with jBloomberg. For example, following code just create a session but there is no Auth data:

```
BloombergSession jBloombergSession = new DefaultBloombergSession();
jBloombergSession.start();
```

I can't find any example of this online.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That file is used in the tests, in particular in [`AuthorisationTest.java`](https://github.com/assylias/jBloomberg/blob/master/src/test/java/com/assylias/jbloomberg/AuthorisationTest.java). If you look at the code in that file you will see a few examples using the different forms of authorisation.